# How to detect wireless charging new iPhone8/X on iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios11, iphone-x, iphone-8

how to detect wireless charging new iPhone8/X on iOS 11? In the UIDevice class there is no this information

Comment: Why would _how_ the device is charging matter?

Comment: You will get a quicker answer on the Apple Developer Forums, if an API is available.

Comment: Quite strange, why there are some people are not happy with this question.

Answer (score 2):

As for now there is not any data for detecting this. On your `UIDevice.current` object you currently have `batteryState` which is an enum of `UIDeviceBatteryState` which currently have:

- unknown
- unplugged
- charging
- full

Maybe Apple will add wireless charing to it in the future.